# How to set jacoco code coverage levels to module in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm using gradle 4.3.1 with the jacoco plugin and I am able to ensure a certain level of code coverage in a a multi module project.  This works great when I set the **element** to **CLASS** or **PACAKAGE**, but I'm stumped on how to get it work for the module.

Looking [here](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/core/analysis/ICoverageNode.ElementType.html) I think what I want is **BUNDLE** or **GROUP**, but then jacoco does not break when I go under the coverage amount.

Here is an example of what I have that does work for package level coverage enforcement :

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            // should be element = 'BUNDLE' or 'GROUP'? 
            element = 'PACKAGE'

            limit {
                minimum = 0.9
            }
            includes = ['com.mypackage.*']
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the element value to BUNDLE the build does not fail regardless of coverage. Again I'd like to be able to control the expectation at the module level.

Here is my gradle version information:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-11-08 08:59:45 UTC
Revision:     e4f4804807ef7c2829da51877861ff06e07e006d

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something pretty simple, since I don't think I'm the first to try to do this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure of this, but could you try adding counter='LINE' inside limit.

```
rule {
       element = 'GROUP'

       limit {
           minimum = 0.9
           counter = 'LINE'
       }
...
```

Apart from that also try to add jacocoTestReport for generating test report to verify your result for internal testing purpose only.

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_configuration

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I had tried the same and it does not change the result.  I have been generating the HTML output and I can see that the total coverage for the module is 85%.